# Solve null date with case or if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, where-clause

I am wanting to process records for dates on an everyday basis. However I have a solution that will work incrementally but I need one that will load the first date if the table is null. Here is my query

```
  SELECT DateToProcess = MIN(MonthlyDate)
  FROM ods.CustomerBill b
  WHERE b.MonthlyDate > @DateToProcess
```

If `@DateToProcess` is null I want to set it to say 1999-01-01 that way it grabs the min date from my table and starts inserting records. How can I implement this additional logic to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap `@DateToProcess` with an `ISNULL`:

```
ISNULL(@DateToProcess,'19000101')
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer explicit logic to magic values, so I would recommend:

```
SELECT DateToProcess = MIN(MonthlyDate)
FROM ods.CustomerBill b
WHERE b.MonthlyDate > @DateToProcess OR @DateToProcess IS NULL
```